How to model data where an individual could be in more than one group within the data, but is more likely to only appear once?
I have multiple cohorts of patients with different index symptoms/events, and am looking to predict cancer risk for each separate cohort, including certain covariates of interest to see which combinations of index event and covariate confer the highest risk. However, the sample size for some cohorts is very small, hence I have been looking into combining all cohorts into one dataframe to improve the confidence in the coefficient estimates. There is a 'random' group which I want to use to model baseline risk, however, a few of the cohorts have been selected from this group, and hence have 100% overlapping patient IDs. Some of the other cohorts are more distinct to this baseline group, with fewer patients overlapping.
The dataframe looks something like:



patid
cohort
sex
smoking_status
bmi_cat
anaemia
platelet_count
wbc_count
cough
vomiting
weight_loss
appetite_loss
dyspepsia
abdominal_pain




001
1
1
2
3
0
0
1
1
0
1
1
0
1


002
1
1
3
2
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
1



The overall joined sample size was approx 1.3 million, with approx 900k unique patients. Each index cohort ranged in size from approx 2k patients to approx 450k patients. The random sample is around 450k patients. Also, the cancer outcome is very rare in the population, ranging from approx 0.2% in one cohort to 3.4% in the cohort with highest incidence.
It was suggested I use a mixed effects model, with the patient ID being the random effect, and including a column indicating cohort membership. However, even the simplest model form results in a large RE SD and risk predictions which are inaccurate based on prior knowledge, and from the individual cohort models.
I have only used ME models before to model multiple measurements from individuals over time, whereas this data is more cross sectional, and the majority of patients do not have multiple measurements.
I am thinking of just subsampling the random sample, and then removing those patients from the main cohorts to run a normal glm(), but is there a better model form out there? Should the mixed effects model work on my data?
Hopefully this is enough information, but I can provide more if I've missed something out.

Welcome to CrossValidated. I am having a little trouble understanding your experimental design. Given your dataframe structure, which variable is the dependent/response ? Also, you mention "There is a random group", but there is no variable named random that determines group membership, as far as I can tell. You say that the results you obtained so far are "inaccurate" -  can you provide more details ? It would also be helpful if you can paste the summary results from your model into your question (use the  link just above here).
